# UIAlertView with textfield do no show fields

Tags: uialertview, textfield, alertview

I am trying to create a UIAlertView which allows you to write comments but the fields do not appear on the AlertView. here the code:

```
UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your opinion"
                                                 message:@"Enter your comment" // IMPORTANT
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Send", nil];



textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[textField setPlaceholder:@"Name"];
textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textField.delegate = self;
[prompt addSubview:textField];

textField2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 85.0, 260.0, 50.0)];
[textField2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[textField2 setPlaceholder:@"Your comment"];
textField2.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textField2.delegate = self;

lblCounter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 120, 10)];
lblCounter.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblCounter.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lblCounter.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.5];

lblCounter.text = @"0/100 characters";

[prompt addSubview:textField2];
[prompt addSubview:lblCounter];


[prompt show];
```

a image sample:

[AlertView Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPb3a.png)

Could anybody help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView is deprecated as of iOS8. Also, it's not intended to be customized in this way: `The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.` (from the docs).

I would suggest either using one of the many replacement libraries like [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView) or rolling your own comment dialog.

If you *must* use UIAlertView, set the alertViewStyle to `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` and change the password text field to show text using `field.secureTextEntry = NO;`